# Equilibrium with step function demand and supply

Tags: microeconomics

How do I solve a system of equations for equilibrium where the demand and supply functions are both step functions?[image]

Comment: There does not seem to be enough information to answer this question. Do you have the equation system? If yes, solve it. Do you have data? The exact solution would depend on the assumptions/market mechanism. If the graph is 'accurate' then the equilibrium is at the intersection, but I am guessing the vertical parts are 'not really there'?